# Why can we substitute $ V_{\mu \nu} $ to $ V_{\mu ; \nu} $ while inducing contracted Bianchi identity?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors, tensor-rank, outer-product

After $ ( A_\mu B_\nu )_{; \sigma ; \rho} - ( A_\mu B_\nu )_{; \rho ; \sigma} = A_\alpha B_\nu R^\alpha_{\mu \rho \sigma} + A_\mu B_\alpha R^\alpha_{\nu \rho \sigma} $ where $ A_\mu B_\nu $ is outer product of two vector $ A_\mu $ and $ B_\nu $, I understand until substituting $ A_\mu B_\nu $ to $ V_{\mu \nu} $ so it becomes $ V_{\mu \nu ; \sigma ; \rho} - V_{\mu \nu ; \rho ; \sigma} = V_{\alpha \nu} R^\alpha_{\mu \rho \sigma} + V_{\mu \alpha} R^\alpha_{\nu \rho \sigma} $. But I don't get the reason why we can substitute $ V_{\mu \nu} $ to $ V_{\mu ; \nu} $ so we get $ V_{\mu ; \sigma ; \rho ; \nu} - V_{\mu ; \rho ; \sigma ; \nu} = V_{\alpha ; \nu} R^\alpha_{\mu \rho \sigma} + V_{\mu ; \alpha} R^\alpha_{\nu \rho \sigma} $. Isn't $ V_{\mu \nu} $ a rank-2 tensor and $ V_{\mu ; \nu} $ a vector?

Comment: I did not check your formulas but the answer to your last question is clearly no. $V_{\mu ; \nu}$ is a rank-$2$ tensor. That is the whole point of introducing covariant derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula
$$
T_{\mu \nu ; \sigma ; \rho} - T_{\mu \nu ; \rho ; \sigma}
= T_{\alpha \nu} R^\alpha_{\mu \rho \sigma} + T_{\mu \alpha} R^\alpha_{\nu \rho \sigma}
$$
holds for all rank-2 tensors $T_{\mu \nu}$. (And $T_{\mu \nu}$ does not have to be of the form $A_\mu B_\nu$.)

In particular, $V_{\mu ; \nu}$ is a rank-2 tensor, so the formula applies to it.

Comment: Could you explain the reason why the formula works for all rank-2 tensors? I'm not sure why $ T_{\mu \nu} $does not have to be of the form of $ A_{\mu} B_{\nu} $

Comment: Great question. While $T$ isn't necessarily of the form $A \otimes B$ (switching styles of notation for the moment), it is a sum of products $A \otimes B$. The sum $T = \sum_{ab} T_{ab} dx^a \otimes dx^b$ is such a decomposition, locally. The formula then works for the sum because it works on each term.

Comment: Woah, I guess I got it. Thank you so much! ദ്ദി*ˊᗜˋ*)